# Google Dev-Admin Memcache Viewer displaying unicode

Tags: python, google-app-engine, unicode, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to stop showing unicode in the Google admin server `Memcache Viewer`? In the past I would copy/paste the id from the Datastore Viewer for a session entity into the `Memcache Viewer` and I could see an (easily human) readable value. Lately it's been displaying in unicode values. eg:

```
\x80\x02}q\x01U\x10tokenq\x02U+UIiJFPcgK7ckS4iAYvzpVdG1DnERTJTAjcLPGchek5kq\x03s.
```

where in the past it would look like:

```
token=UIiJFPcgK7ckS4iAYvzpVdG1DnERTJTAjcLPGchek5k
```

I tried Chrome and IE (on Windows 8.1). In Chrome I have gone into the menu>Tools>encoding and experimented with different encoding to no avail.

Here is the Google issue I created: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10870

**Here is a workaround in the meantime:**

1. Go to your datastore viewer and copy the key of the session object
2. Go to the interactive console (eg. localhost:8000/console)

   from google.appengine.api import memcache
   print memcache.get('paste-the-key-name-here')
   You should have readable content again :D

Comment: Verified this occurs on a latest OS MacBook Pro (so it's not a Win8/64 issue only). It must be a bug introduced in a recent SDK release. Filed a bug and haven't heard anything as of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the browser's Encoding setting.  In Chrome for example, it's on the View menu.

Comment: I've tried every setting under the encoding menu and it has no effect.